# Using GSON to parse an object with mixed types

Tags: java, android, gson

I'm using a webservice which unfortunately I don't have any control over, there is one element called price that can have 2 types of values, it can either be a double:

```
price: 263.12
```

or a string with a specific format:

```
price: "263.12;Y"
```

In the second case the ;N indicates that the price can be modified (ie: a discount can be added), I tried to convince the developers of the service to modify the response and send the Y or N (depending on the case) in a separate value (discount: "Y" | "N:), but they said that for now they won't do it.

Within the POJO I declared for this case, I have the following case:

```
private float precio;
public void setPrice(String value){
    if(value.indexOf(";") == -1){
        price = Float.parseFloat(value);
    } else {
        String[] p = value.split(";");
        price = Float.parseFloat(p[0]);
    }
}
public float getPrice(){return price;}
```

But unfortunately using:

```
Product obj = new Gson().fromJson(response, Product.class);
```

Never actually cals the setter, in the cases where the price is set as a proper double it works just fine, but where I'm receiving the string it just crashes, any suggestions on how this could be handled, worst case scenario I could create a second POJO and try/catch the object creation, but there should be a better idea and searching so far has yielded no results.

Comment: `void setPrie(`... Isn't method name missing something ?

Comment: right click, source, generate getters and setters: no risk of such mistake

Comment: AFAIK Gson does not use properties but fields only, so this is not related to the issue.

Comment: @JT: is your POJO complex? Because if not too complex you could create a proxy with a price field typed as a string and map it to your business POJO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement a `TypeAdapter` that overwrites the default serialization. You have to register that `TypeAdapter` for a certain class ...

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
builder.registerTypeAdapter(Product.class, new ProductAdapter());
Gson gson = builder.create();
```

... so this way any members of type `Product` ...

```
String jsonString = gson.toJson(somethingThatContainsProducts);
```

... will be handled by the `TypeAdapter`:

```
public class ProductAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Product> {

  public Product read(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
    if (reader.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
      reader.nextNull();
      return null;
    }

    String json = reader.nextString();

    // convert String to product ... assuming Product has a 
    // constructor that creates an instance from a String
    return new Product(json);
  }

  public void write(JsonWriter writer, Product value) throws IOException {
    if (value == null) {
      writer.nullValue();
      return;
    }

    // convert Product to String .... assuming Product has a method getAsString()
    String json = value.getAsString();
    writer.value(json);
  }
}
```

Check out the Google [GSON documentation](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html) for more.

Hope this helps ... Cheers!

Comment: You assume a lot of things, here is my try: "// assuming there is nothing to do" ;) More seriously though handling the raw JSON parsing/serializing is a viable solution it can be quite complicated. It's why I prefer the idea of a proxy that lets GSON do the hard work...What do you think? :)

Comment: :D just an outline of how it could look like. If `Product` is a bigger class and `price` is just a member variable of many others, then consider to use an own class for `Price` and implement a conversion for that only. The conversion is the same as you have in your `setPrice(String value)` method. This way GSON is still doing the "hard work" and you can implement a custom conversion :) To do this just create a small `Price` class, use that in the `TypeAdapter<Price>` and apply your existing price conversion .

Comment: I like this idea too :) It will depend of what the OP can do with the entities because if they are used by a business layer he may not have the latitude to change them.

Comment: You really like to make things more complicated, don't you? ;-) I can think of two approaches, if the price member can't be changed: 1. either build a wrapper class for `Product` or 2. write a `TypeAdapter` for the `String` type that is able to detect the price member variables; both have its restrictions and may not be applicable for you - sorry then! ;)

Comment: I don't like complex things (because I can't handle them) but when I have no info I prepare for the worst case scenario ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could write a `TypeAdapter` or `JsonDeserializer`.

You can also just rely on the fact that Gson will massage types for you and go the other way with your type:

```
class Pojo { String price; }
...
String json = "{\"price\":1234.5}";
Pojo p = new Gson().fromJson(json, Pojo.class);
System.out.println(p.price);
```

produces:

> 1234.5

When you want to access/get `price` as a `double` , convert it appropriately in the getter.